# How to add a marker in flutter to the Yandex MapKit?

Tags: flutter, dart, yandex-maps, yandex-mapkit

How to add a marker in flutter (as far as I understand, this is placemark, but after studying the documentation. I haven't found how to add it. marker on the map) on the map? I use Yandex Mapkit

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  final List<MapObject> mapObjects = [];
  final placemarks = [
      Placemark(
         mapId: MapObjectId('placemark_3'),
         point const Point(latitude: 55.69494398296744, longitude: 37.653375915527334),
         ....
           
      ),
     ...
  ];
   setState(() {
       mapObjects.addAll(placemarks);
  });
```